# NSPredicate Value matching between NSArray and NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, nsarray, nspredicate

I've one `NSArray` (`self.allUsers`) with `PFUser` object inside :

```
"<PFUser: 0x7ff578f501f0, objectId: qvFwzbBGky, localId: (null)> {\n    friends = \"<PFRelation: 0x7ff578f4eef0, 0x0.(null) -> _User>\";\n    phone = 0;\n    surname = test;\n    username = \"test@gmail.com\";\n}"
```

I can access phone number with `[self.allUsers valueForKey:@"phone"]`

I have another `NSArray` (`self.sectionedPersonName`) with `NSObject` **Person** inside (sorted by section). I can access phone number with `person.number`.

I would like to compare the phone number between these two arrays. and log when that match the `PFUser` objectId (`[self.allUsers valueForKey:@"objectId"];`)

Maybe I've to use `NSPredicate` CONTAINS ?
I don't know if it's possible with NSObject and PFUser.

After, I would like to change color of cell that matches.

And in didSelect, just Log objectId from `PFUser` when I click on it. We have to make a correspondence between PFUser and NSObject...

I succeed to display objectId for PFUser that matches :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        Person *person = [[self.sectionedPersonName objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = person.fullName;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = person.number;

        if ( [[self.allUsers valueForKey:@"phone"] containsObject:person.number] ) {
            // do found
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
Person *person = [[self.sectionedPersonName objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        __block PFUser *foundedPFUser;
        NSMutableArray *realResult   = [NSMutableArray new];
        [self.tableData enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Person *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSArray *result = [self.allUsers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", @"phone", obj.number]];
            if(result.count){
                [realResult addObjectsFromArray:result];
            }
        }];

        NSLog(@"%@",realResult);

        if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark){
            NSLog(@"%@", person.number);
        }
        else{

        }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Now, I when I tap on a cell, that log :

1. The number of the person I click on.
2. The three PFUser that match with number

Log :

```
2015-08-31 12:02:59.727 ChillN[691:18988] (
    "<PFUser: 0x7f992a4df7e0, objectId: bEO3D62Cvo, localId: (null)> {\n    friends = \"<PFRelation: 0x7f992a4a3b60, 0x0.(null) -> _User>\";\n    phone = 5555228243;\n    surname = test4;\n    username = \"test4@gmail.com\";\n}",
    "<PFUser: 0x7f992a4a3d30, objectId: rlG21mKFJZ, localId: (null)> {\n    friends = \"<PFRelation: 0x7f992a4e08d0, 0x0.(null) -> _User>\";\n    phone = 31560987;\n    surname = test2;\n    username = \"test2@gmail.com\";\n}",
    "<PFUser: 0x7f992a47af90, objectId: 7X0OVanRZ9, localId: (null)> {\n    friends = \"<PFRelation: 0x7f992a4e0970, 0x0.(null) -> _User>\";\n    phone = 7075551854;\n    surname = test3;\n    username = \"test3@gmail.com\";\n}"
)
2015-08-31 12:02:59.727 ChillN[691:18988] 5555228243
```

Now I would like that match only the good `PFUser`. When I click on "Anna Haro", find that the `person.number` is **5555228243**, and find in `PFUser` "5555228243", and Log the objectId of `PFUser`.

What I'm expecting :

Log :

```
2015-08-31 12:02:59.727 ChillN[691:18988] (
    "<PFUser: 0x7f992a4df7e0, objectId: bEO3D62Cvo, localId: (null)> {\n    friends = \"<PFRelation: 0x7f992a4a3b60, 0x0.(null) -> _User>\";\n    phone = 5555228243;\n    surname = test4;\n    username = \"test4@gmail.com\";\n}"
)
2015-08-31 12:02:59.727 ChillN[691:18988] 5555228243
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood correctly

```
  PFUser *pfUser1 = [PFUser new];
  pfUser1.objectId = @"qvFwzbBGky";
  pfUser1.phone    = @"123";

  PFUser *pfUser2 = [PFUser new];
  pfUser2.objectId = @"bar";
  pfUser2.phone    = @"987";

  NSArray *allUsers = @[ pfUser1, pfUser2 ];

  Person *person = [Person new];
  person.phoneNumber = @"123";

  NSArray *anotherArray = @[ person ];


  __block BOOL found;
  __block PFUser *foundedPFUser;
  [anotherArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Person *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

      NSArray *result = [allUsers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[c] %@", @"phone", obj.phoneNumber]];

      if(result.count){

          found = YES;
          foundedPFUser = result.firstObject;
          *stop = YES;
      }

  }];

  NSLog(@"");
```

[image: and result]

This code is better than old v.

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
      __block PFUser *foundedPFUser;
      NSMutableArray *realResult   = [NSMutableArray new];
      [self.tableData enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Person *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
          NSArray *result = [self.allUsers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[c] %@", @"phone", obj.number]];
          if(result.count){
              [realResult addObjectsFromArray:result];
          }
      }];

      NSLog(@"%@",realResult);
  }
```

Comment: Nice, thanks man! but that gives me only one PFUser (the last one who match), I would like to add every PFUser in result NSArray.

Comment: Edited my answer. np.

Comment: Nice edit ! :) We are close that I'm expected. I've edited my post with cellForRow, image and Log. Thank you so much...

Comment: No, I would like to log only the pfuser I'm clicking on row … do you know how to make that?

Comment: I changed :             NSArray *result = [self.allUsers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K = %@", @"phone", obj.number]]; I edited my post for what I'm expecting for NSLog

Comment: Found it, just add a loop :             for (PFUser *user in result)
            {
                if ( [[result valueForKey:@"phone"] containsObject:person.number] ) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", user.objectId);
                }